# add attribute of customer with primary

Tags: magento2, custom-attributes

I want to add an attribute of customer,like phone number,how to add an attribute for primary
I find source like this

```
$eavSetup->addAttribute(
            Customer::ENTITY,
                'mobile_phone',
                [
                    'group' => 'General',
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'label' => 'Mobile Phone',
                    'input' => 'text',
                    'source' => '',
                    'frontend' => '',
                    'backend' => '',
                    'required' => false,
                    'sort_order' => 66,
                    'global' => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                    'is_used_in_grid' => false,
                    'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
                    'is_filterable_in_grid' => false,
                    'visible' => true,
                    'is_html_allowed_on_front' => true,
                    'visible_on_front' => true
                ]
        );
$CustomerAttribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'mobile_phone');
        $CustomerAttribute ->addData(
            [
                'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_create']
            ]
        );
```

but it doesn't primary attribute

Comment: Primary means required field?

Comment: what do you mean by primary ? you want this attribute to be part of the primary key that identify the customer entity ?

Comment: @Claims it mean this attribute identify the customer entity

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the magento core method to do that (never tried it on my own though)

`addPrimaryKeyIfExists` from `src/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/SchemaListener.php`

```
/**
 * Add primary key if exists in definition.
 *
 * @param string $tableName
 * @param string $columnName
 * @param array $definition
 * @param string $primaryKeyName
 * @return array
 */
private function addPrimaryKeyIfExists($tableName, $columnName, $definition, $primaryKeyName)
{
    if (isset($definition['primary']) && $definition['primary']) {
        $dataToLog['constraints']['primary'][$primaryKeyName] = [
            'type' => 'primary',
            'name' => $primaryKeyName,
            'disabled' => false,
            'columns' => [$columnName => strtolower($columnName)]
        ];

        $this->log($tableName, $dataToLog);
    }

    unset($definition['primary']);
    return $definition;
}
```

It's a private method called by

```
/**
 * Add column.
 *
 * @param string $tableName
 * @param string $columnName
 * @param array $definition
 * @param string $primaryKeyName
 * @param string|null $onCreate
 */
public function addColumn($tableName, $columnName, $definition, $primaryKeyName = 'PRIMARY', $onCreate = null)
{
    $definition = $this->castColumnDefinition($definition, $columnName);
    $definition = $this->addPrimaryKeyIfExists($tableName, $columnName, $definition, $primaryKeyName);
    $definition['onCreate'] = $onCreate;
    $dataToLog['columns'][strtolower($columnName)] = $definition;
    $this->log($tableName, $dataToLog);
}
```

Hoping this will lead you somewhere. That being said i'm note sure about the fact of adding a primary key to a core customer functionnality, it could have much more impact than you though about.